# Приложение некорректно работает и ругается на KERNELBASE.dll

Tags: delphi

Написал программу, у меня все пашет нормально (WindowsXP):

[image]

А вот у знакомого (2 компа Windows7) не пашет:
[image]

После установки выдает окно о том, что программа возможно установлена неправильно. При удалении и на ноуте, и на компе выдает тоже самое, но удаляет. И сама программа у меня не запустилась.

В логах:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
<Provider Name="Application Error" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>100</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-11-29T13http://www.webtalking.ru/images/smilies/22.gif06.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>1644</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>Б_комната-ПК</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
- <EventData>
<Data>OnlainMovie.exe</Data>
<Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
<Data>2a425e19</Data>
<Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
<Data>6.1.7600.16385</Data>
<Data>4a5bdbdf</Data>
<Data>0eedfade</Data>
<Data>0000b727</Data>
<Data>4e8</Data>
<Data>01ccae99e10eb300</Data>
<Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\OnlainMovie\OnlainMovie.exe</Data>
<Data>C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
<Data>216add20-1a8d-11e1-a97a-20cf30c4dadf</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Не подскажете, из-за чего может быть ошибка?

Comment: Ну если ты сам писал программу, то кому как не тебе знать что и в каком случае она пишет в логи :)

Comment: программу писал я, но это логи не программы, а виндовса на котором запускалась прога... проверил на двух других компах с виндой7... работает нормально!

Comment: Эх, вот к чему приводит неосмысленный копипаст - писал вроде сам, а что делает программа ... ну вы поняли мораль...

Comment: очередной вопрос из разряда - ищу опытного программиста экстрасенса...

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего что программа не совместима с x64 битной версии Windows 7.

P.S. Ты же сам программу писал, я надеюсь, значит ты и должен был знать из-за чего ошибка, так как всё твоих рук дел и логи, как я понимаю были придуманы тобой, а не левым дядем.

Comment: P.S.S. Не «Onlain», а «Online».